# Apple Sign In not working in Xcode, Simulator (IOS) - Meteor Cordova build. It works ok in Safari pre-build (web/js only)

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, meteor, apple-sign-in

Implemented quave:accounts-apple as follows:
Meteor 1.10
init.js:

```
ServiceConfiguration.configurations.upsert(   
      { service: "apple" },
      {
        $set: {
          nativeClientId: "myappid#",
          clientId: "com.mysiteurl",
          teamId: "myteamid",
          keyId: "mykeyid",
          secret: "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n ...text...  \n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----",
          redirectUri: "https://mysiteurl.com:443/_oauth/apple",
          scope: "name%20email",
          responseMode: "form_post",
          responseType: "code",
          service: "apple",
      loginStyle: "popup"
        }
      }
    );
```

I also added the following as an event in the atForm:

```
'click #at-apple': function(){
        Meteor.loginWithApple({
            requestPermissions: ['name', 'email'],
          });
    }
```

but this

> Meteor.loginWithApple

function doesn’t seem to make a difference one way or another.

Facebook, Twitter, Google oauth work aok.

In Safari, this generally works ok (I can’t login successfully, but I do get the popup and prompt with the correct wording for “register” vs “sign in”):
[image: safari]
[image: safari sign-in]

But after running the build command and opening the project in Xcode, when I run the app in Simulator, I get no popup upon pressing the button and the button reads “Configure Apple” only. I did add “Sign in with Apple” in Signing & Capabilities but not sure if additional configuration is required there?

Is the

> Configure Apple

a clue as to what is wrong?

[image: simulator register]
[image: simulator sign-in]

Answer (score 0):

Any of the "login with apple" packages contain a dependency on a cordova plugin for apple login? Such as https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-sign-in-with-apple